# Override Route class in component

Tags: joomla, url-routing

How can I override `class Route` in my component. I need this to rewrite the url the way I need it. I tried with creating file `route.php` and extending the `Route` class. But couldn't call it in the view. I am talking about this file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Joomla! Content Management System
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2018 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

namespace Joomla\CMS\Router;

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;

/**
 * Route handling class
 *
 * @since  11.1
 */
class Route
{
    /**
     * The route object so we don't have to keep fetching it.
     *
     * @var    Router
     * @since  12.2
     */
    private static $_router = null;

    /**
     * Translates an internal Joomla URL to a humanly readable URL.
     *
     * @param   string   $url    Absolute or Relative URI to Joomla resource.
     * @param   boolean  $xhtml  Replace & by &amp; for XML compliance.
     * @param   integer  $ssl    Secure state for the resolved URI.
     *                             0: (default) No change, use the protocol currently used in the request
     *                             1: Make URI secure using global secure site URI.
     *                             2: Make URI unsecure using the global unsecure site URI.
     *
     * @return string The translated humanly readable URL.
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function _($url, $xhtml = true, $ssl = null)
    {
        if (!self::$_router)
        {
            // Get the router.
            $app = Factory::getApplication();
            self::$_router = $app::getRouter();

            // Make sure that we have our router
            if (!self::$_router)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (!is_array($url) && (strpos($url, '&') !== 0) && (strpos($url, 'index.php') !== 0))
        {
            return $url;
        }

        // Build route.
        $uri = self::$_router->build($url);

        $scheme = array('path', 'query', 'fragment');

        /*
         * Get the secure/unsecure URLs.
         *
         * If the first 5 characters of the BASE are 'https', then we are on an ssl connection over
         * https and need to set our secure URL to the current request URL, if not, and the scheme is
         * 'http', then we need to do a quick string manipulation to switch schemes.
         */
        if ((int) $ssl || $uri->isSsl())
        {
            static $host_port;

            if (!is_array($host_port))
            {
                $uri2 = Uri::getInstance();
                $host_port = array($uri2->getHost(), $uri2->getPort());
            }

            // Determine which scheme we want.
            $uri->setScheme(((int) $ssl === 1 || $uri->isSsl()) ? 'https' : 'http');
            $uri->setHost($host_port[0]);
            $uri->setPort($host_port[1]);
            $scheme = array_merge($scheme, array('host', 'port', 'scheme'));
        }

        $url = $uri->toString($scheme);

        // Replace spaces.
        $url = preg_replace('/\s/u', '%20', $url);

        if ($xhtml)
        {
            $url = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
        }

        return $url;
    }
}
```

Want to make changes in the function and create the url as per my needs. Thank you!

Comment: For URL rewriting, you can use the router.php file to rewrite URLs, of your component ,they way you want. It either extends `JComponentRouterBase` or `JComponentRouterView`.
  You can then make use of the `build` and `parse` functions.

Comment: I didn't see where i can rewrite my url in these methods. They are returning some query and vars. Where vars seems to be array with fixed keys - task,view,id.

Comment: Okay then can you please explain a little bit about what actually do you want to change in the URL? Thanks

Comment: I want to put the car details in it. Like getting data from db table and construct for example: mysite.com/carmake-caryear-carmodel

Comment: Yes that what the `router.php` file in a component is for. You create a non-sef URL from the view or anywhere and then in the `router.php` file, you simply manipulate the incoming request and create a SEF URL from that.

Comment: Look at the official Joomla documentation here [link](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component)